# How to remove the delay in jQuery .hover() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, delay

I tried to make my nav element change color as the document scrolls, I also want to make the hover state change color dynamically. But there's a delay, I have to wait for a fraction of seconds before I can hover and change the color. Can I remove the delay? Or better, when I am hovering on a menu, can I make the hovered color change by scrolling? I feel like I'm so close to the solution yet I can't find it.

Here are the jQuery codes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var h = $(window).scrollTop() / $(document).height() * 360;
        if (h <= 180) {
            hhover = h + 180;
        } else {
            hhover = h - 180;
        }
        $("a").css({
            "color":"hsl(" + h + ",100%,50%)","transition":"0.2s ease"});
        $("a").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css(
                "color", "hsl(" + hhover + ",100%,50%)");
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css(
                "color", "hsl(" + h + ",100%,50%)");
        });
    });
});
```

Please find my jsFiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/dtZDZ/1036/

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about the unspecific questions. You can forget about the second question. Even when I removed the .2s transition, there is still delay between when I finished scrolling. Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dtZDZ/1038/

Comment: try to delete `"transition":"0.2s ease"` when you set styles in  `hover ` callback

Comment: remove transition from nav-links a:hover CSS rule -> https://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/dtZDZ/1040/

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code:

```
.nav-links a:hover {
    color: hsl(180,100%,50%);
    transition: ease;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my fiddle but there's still delay even after removing the .2s transition. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/dtZDZ/1039/

Comment: Here is a short video illustrating my jsFiddle result: tinypic.com/r/346me85/8

Answer (score -1):

Delete all CSS transition definitions from javascript code and from styles.

Comment: When I hover on links I don't see delay. Color changes very fast

Comment: Here is a short video illustrating my jsFiddle result: http://tinypic.com/r/346me85/8